# MySQL query - more elegant option? Referencing same column name in multiple tables in a SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, where-clause

I have several tables in a MySQL database for which most SELECT queries will reference a column of the same name for the same value in each table.

So for instance, the tables (bnsf, train_plan, train_type, and operation_costs) will **ALL** have a field called '**train_id**'.

Depending on the record/row, the value on the 'train_id' column could be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. But most of the time in a query, the desired results will all be for the records where these values match a given value, such as "**2**".

> So a query like this works:

```
SELECT * FROM (((bnsf
INNER JOIN train_plan ON bnsf.train_id = train_plan.train_id)
INNER JOIN train_type ON train_plan.train_id = train_type.train_id)
INNER JOIN operation_costs ON train_type.train_id = operation_costs.train_id)
WHERE bnsf.train_id = 2
 AND train_plan.train_id = 2
 AND train_type.train_id = 2
 AND operation_costs.train_id = 2;
```

> Is there a simpler way of writing that query (specifically the WHERE
>   clause)? Essentially, something like this:

```
WHERE `train_id` IN TABLE(bnsf, train_plan, train_type, operation_costs) = 2;
// invalid syntax
```

I'd like to avoid having AND, AND, AND - and having to repeat the same value for each table. What I have works but doesn't seem very elegant. Any ideas?

*I've spent a long time reading other posts, but I'm not liking the suggestions with unions, etc. (Don't seem to be any shorter)*

Comment: 2 IN(a.train_id,b.train_id,c.train_id,d.train_id) -- another idea, albeit a slightly different one.

Comment: Thanks! @Strawberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join conditions make all but the first  WHERE clauses redundant.

```
INNER JOIN train_plan ON bnsf.train_id = train_plan.train_id)
```

Only `train_plan` rows matching the `bnsf.train_id` are selected, and similarly for 
the other tables joined further.

So when you say,

```
WHERE bnsf.train_id = 2
```

And then you join the other tables on that column, you can be guaranteed that they'll all equal the same thing.

```
SELECT * FROM (((bnsf
INNER JOIN train_plan ON bnsf.train_id = train_plan.train_id)
INNER JOIN train_type ON train_plan.train_id = train_type.train_id)
INNER JOIN operation_costs ON train_type.train_id = operation_costs.train_id)
WHERE bnsf.train_id = 2
```

That's a perfectly reasonable query.